# Как получить ссылку со страницы в WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview

Есть страница `contentFinal`, которая загружается в `WebView` через фильтры `Jsoup`. В загруженной странице есть ссылки, ведущие на другие страницы сайта.

```
    WebView cntContent;
    WebView cntComments;
    WebSettings webSettingsContent;
    WebSettings webSettingsComments;

        cntContent = findViewById(R.id.cntContent);
        cntComments = findViewById(R.id.cntComments);
        webSettingsContent = cntContent.getSettings();
        webSettingsComments = cntComments.getSettings();
        webSettingsContent.setDefaultFontSize(16);
        webSettingsComments.setDefaultFontSize(16);

        cntContent.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        cntComments.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        webSettingsContent.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettingsComments.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

        cntContent.loadDataWithBaseURL(contentUrl, contentFinal, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        cntComments.loadDataWithBaseURL(contentUrl, commentsFinal, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        cntContent.setClickable(true);
```

**Как заполучить url ссылки при клике на нее пользователем?** **И как отследить именно клик на ссылке?** Т.е. мне необходимо отследить клик пользователя на ссылку и заключить ее в, например, `String userUrl`. Далее, я уже переназначу действие.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помогли на англоязычном ресурсе.

```
WebView wv = new WebView();
 wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                String url = request.getUrl().toString();
                return false;
            }
        });
```